# Get records from Primary key of first table and Foreign key of second table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `first_table` and `second_table` primary key of first_table is `s_id` and it has following values 1,2,3,4 and primary key of second_table and foriegn key of first table is `fk__sid` which have values 1,2,3 .

The problem is that I want to get all the fields of first table where primary key of first_table and foreign key of second table matches and also those values whose primary key is there but no foreign key in other table.

for ex: for the fields of the value 4

Comment: ok. So what have you tried so far?

Comment: show us the tables structures

Comment: You need a `LEFT JOIN` to select values that don't have foreign key in right table (second table)

Comment: Are these two separate queries? Because selecting everything in the first_table will get what you have described.

Comment: i mean the values of primary key which are not yet used as the foreign key of second table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM first_table LEFT JOIN second_table ON first_table.s_id = second_table.fk_sid;
```